# Microsoft Bot Framework Example Speech to Text Bot - clientid and clientSecret

Tags: c#, windows, botframework

### UPDATE and GitHub Examples

To see the code of the sample on Speech to Text see the [Microsoft Bot Builder GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText). I have some personal examples on my GitHub as well starting with my[LUISBankingBot](https://github.com/gregdegruy/LUISBankingBot).

### Original Post

Trouble getting started with the [Example Speech to Text Bot](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-intelligence/speech/#example-speech-to-text-bot). In the code snippet it asks for a clientid and clientSecret, but I am not sure where to find these. In my [Free Subscriptions](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions) (Bing Search - Free in particular) I have only a *Key 1* and *Key 2*, not sure where the clientid and clientSecret information could live. I believe I can not move forward in the tutorial unless some help is given on where I can find the clientid and clientSecret information.

Thanks for the help! Happy botting!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Greg, glad you figured it out on your own. My team wrote the example and the new sample code in Github. I understand the confusion. We'll make some edits to make the mapping of userid->clientid and apikey->clientsecret more clear. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the very quick help here John, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suuuuper simple oversight here. The naming threw me off in the code sample, but check it!

tl;dr

```
UserID = clientID
ApiKey = clientSecret
```

The class header for the Authentication class has params *clientId* and *clientSecret*... but wait a minutes...

```
public Authentication(string clientId, string clientSecret)
```

When making an instance of an Authentication, the current code snippet as of the writing of this post has the params for you to the fill in as

```
YOURUSERID
```

and

`<YOUR API KEY FROM MICROSOFT.COM/COGNITIVE`

```
Authentication auth = new Authentication("YOURUSERID", "<YOUR API KEY FROM MICROSOFT.COM/COGNITIVE");
```

So another way of looking at this is  :

```
YOURUSERID = clientID
<YOUR API KEY FROM MICROSOFT.COM/COGNITIVE = clientSecret
```

That's it.

Comment: FYI - There is a new SpeechToText sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText

Comment: @EzequielJadib nice! Updates 2 days ago, I'll take a look.

Comment: I think you're pointing at the same sample? ;-)  Either way, I pinged the team that created it and they're going to make it clearer. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Oops, I did a very very quick scan of the code. I will update the post to remove the "new" word.