# Client id for bing speech api with bot framework

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to use `Bing's speech API` like in the example on the [Bot Framework website](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-intelligence/speech/), but the authentication call to get an access token keeps returning this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I believe that's because I'm using an invalid client ID and I really can't find where to get a client ID from.

This is the corresponding line:

```
this.token = HttpPost(AccessUri, this.request);
```

I'm getting the subscription key or client secret from the speech `api` page, but I don't know from where I shall get the client id ?

all the websites given are only giving the user the subscription key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Bot Framework Example Speech to Text Bot - clientid and clientSecret](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884809/microsoft-bot-framework-example-speech-to-text-bot-clientid-and-clientsecret)

Comment: that post is not mentioning how to get the client id

Comment: Use the same key you get from the cognitive services page. You can see that in the sample mentioned in the other post: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText/Services/Authentication.cs#L63

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a key for Bing Speech on the Cognitive Services subscription page:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions

Comment: Yes , this is the client secret I assume , but what about the client id ?

Comment: It's the same one: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText/Services/Authentication.cs#L63